# Ideas on how to clean remote DB before running selenium tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a project where we have created a set of selenium tests, using rspec and capybara, that run against a remote server. This means that these tests do not run in the same Rails instance/environment as the application and, therefore, do not have access to that applications rake tasks.

What we are trying to figure out is a good method of cleaning/restoring the database before each run. We deploy the application via a Jenkins build task and then, if successful, kick of the selenium tests. We are using Selenium2 and the tests are run via SeleniumServer (formerly Selenium Grid). We do have the capability of firing off a Cap task when we deploy the application to restore the DB.

The question is how to do the restore while minimizing the number of migrations that we need to do (preferably limiting migrations to only the most recent ones) and pre-seeding the database with the required data.

Some interesting things to note about our setup: we have a fair bit of information to seed, not Gigs of it, but more than what you would want to enter into a seeds file and we have a fully partitioned database with both public and private schemas. We have a multi-tenant application and use private schemas to isolate data access.

So, what are some of the ways that other people have used to solve this problem?

I think most people use database-cleaner for this problem, but as I said at the beginning, the selenium tests are running outside of the Rails environment so database-cleaner won't work.

Comment: If this is a test server, then you can open a remote connection to the database from the cucumber environment and do anything you like, for example cleaning db with database-cleaner or just execute plan sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jenkins, you could build another Jenkins job that is solely responsible for resetting / refreshing your database. This could contain scripts in your flavor of choice for cleaning up the database. Then set your current Jenkins testing job as a downstream project that gets kicked off upon the successful execution of your cleanup job.

Then when you want to kickoff a full test, just run the cleanup job and go make a sandwich :)